# Why examples of IOC have only OneInterface : OneClass ratio?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, service-locator

I didn't understand that in all examples of IOC i could find, one interface can only have one implemented class in the dictionary of class mapping. Whatever DI or Service locator

It's a little bit stupid in my mind, no?

Comment: Please use a less offensive example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the DI Containers I walk through in [my book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182501) support multiple registrations of the same interface:

**Castle Windsor**

```
container.Register(Component
    .For<IIngredient>()
    .ImplementedBy<Steak>());
container.Register(Component
    .For<IIngredient>()
    .ImplementedBy<SauceBéarnaise>());
```

**Autofac**

```
builder.RegisterType<SauceBéarnaise>().As<IIngredient>();
builder.RegisterType<Steak>().As<IIngredient>();
```

**Unity**

```
container.RegisterType<IIngredient, Steak>();
container.RegisterType<IIngredient, SauceBéarnaise>("sauce");
```

There are more containers that support this; these are only examples. My book contains much more detailed examples.

Comment: Please don't use affiliate links for your book - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2716/affiliate-links-amazon-and-others